# Общие вопросы по настройке торговой площадки, подскажите, если кто-то реализовавал такого рода проекты

Tags: php, post, платежи

Здравствуйте. 
Допустим есть на **сайт**, где пользователи разграничены по ролям: админ, продавец, покупатель.

У каждого продавца есть личный кабинет, через который он может создавать свои товары.

Сайт прикручен к платежному агрегатору (яндекс, робокасса, и т.д. не принципиально)

При покупке, я так понимаю, все деньги перечисляются на общий баланс магазина (в личный кабинет платежного агрегатора), а у продавца в личном кабинете на **сайте** при условии успешной покупки меняется его виртуальный баланс.

**Так вот вопрос:** как продавец может вывести деньги на свой электронный кошелек атвоматически, не уведомляя об этом главного админа. Есть ли у платежных агрегаторов соответствующее API, чтобы деньги перечислялись с одного кошелька на другой, все чаще приходится сталкиваться с такой потребностью.
Правильное ли это направление или вывод средств с подобных сервисов работает как то по-другому?

Мне сейчас нужна больше общая информация чтобы понять принцип работы такого рода сервиса без углубления в технические подробности.

Comment: Ваш вопрос скорее всего породит дискуссию,что нежелательно. Найди хоть частичный ответ на свой вопрос http://www.free-kassa.ru/faq.php , или где нибудь еще.А потом конкретизируй вопрос так чтоб на него смогли ответить точно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от выбранного платежного агрегатора.

Поясню на примере разработанного шлюза для WooCommerce. Шлюз посылает в банк (в моем случае) информацию о товаре, номере заказа и **торговце** (идентификаторе виртуального магазина в банке, со своим отдельным счетом). Клиент вводит номер карточки на сайте банка. Назад банк возвращает в мой шлюз информацию о статусе покупки и номере заказа. Шлюз меняет статус заказа в системе WooCommerce.

Шлюзу все равно, сколько торговцев в системе. Идентификатор торговца можно привязать к товару.

Весь вопрос в том, примет ли банк или иной платежный агрегатор запрос на проведение операции с одного и того же IP, но с разными идентификаторами **торговца**. Если да, то такую площадку можно сделать.

В этом случае на одном **сайте** можно разместить несколько **торговцев**, у каждого в банке будет свой расчетный счет (или кошелек у агрегатора). Никаких переводов между счетами/кошельками делать не надо.

Вам стоит уточнить у конкретных агрегаторов - поддерживают ли они несколько торговцев(магазинов) на одном доменном имени (или IP-адресе). В Интернете я такую информацию не нашел.